# Get Path File From Uri in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I Cant Get Path File From Uri In Zip File Type Or APK file Type. In onActivityResult

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`

`intent.setType("*/*");`

`startActivityForResult(intent, KeyGallery);`

//For Get Path

`String picturePath = data.getData().getPath();`

I receive /document/415 :|

Please Help me

Comment: what's wrong with  /document/415? what do you supposed to get?

Comment: Dont try to convert an uri to a file system path. Use the uri itself.

Answer (score 0):

> It's Work For Me!
>
> Use:
>
> ```
> String path = data.getData().getPath() // "/mnt/sdcard/FileName.mp3"
> File file = new File(new URI(path));
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> String path = data.getData().toString() // "file:///mnt/sdcard/FileName.mp3"
> File file = new File(new URI(path));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get the file path.

```
public static String getFilePath(Context context, Uri uri) {
        String imagePath;
        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, filePath, null, null, null);
        assert c != null;
        c.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
        imagePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
        c.close();
        return imagePath;
    }
```

Hope this helps! Happy Coding!