# Android list all files in drectory from SCHEME_CONTENT uri

Tags: android, file-access

I want the get a list of files in same directory of a given single file from uri e.g [picture #1.1]

```
content://org.owncloud.documents/document/79
```

[image]

and then select file [picture #1.2]
[image]

when I select requested fields

```
val filePath = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, DISPLAY_NAME, RELATIVE_PATH)
val c: Cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri!!, filePath, null, null, null)!!
c.moveToFirst()
```

I receive [picture #1.3]

[image]

within this directory e.g `content://org.owncloud.documents/document/79`

**Solution 1 :**

Query it, but something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/65070765/1079990 doesn't work.
I guess I've grab directory from it and then query all files.
***This is the main question !***

**Solution 2 :**

Select the directory directly with eg.

```
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
            startActivityForResult(intent, 123)
```

[image]

But here I can't access **ownCloud**, how to be able to select this as well ?

Comment: You posted the wrong picture. Please post the one where ownCloud was choosed. Not the device storage.

Comment: Did you query the file uri for column DISPLAY_NAME and RELATIVE_PATH? Please do and tell.

Comment: First, @blackapps I posted now [picture #1.2] which shows (as requested) when I select file

Comment: Cant you pick directory `Gesundheit` using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE?

Comment: Second, I posted [picture #1.3] to answer your second suggestion

Comment: Third: As described in Solution 2 : I can't select any directory, because root "ownCloud" is not displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248873/discussion-between-hannes-ach-and-blackapps).

Comment: Not displayed? But i see it clearly in your first picture. And we will not chat.

Comment: Ok, no chat. It answer question "Did you query the file uri for column DISPLAY_NAME and RELATIVE_PATH? Please do and tell."

Answer (score 1):

First if ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE cannot give you the tree then what you want will be impossible.

Second if you used ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT you got an uri for a file. And permission to read and or write it.

Even if you could manage to build up an uri for the directory the file was  in (quite possible if you choosed a file from device storage)  you would not have permission to read it.

Comment: It's not solved, but I give you the 10 reputation for the afford

Comment: Youre so kind ;-) But i had rather seen you answering why you did not select the Gesundheid directory.

Comment: Because I can't select it ! "Third: As described in Solution 2 : I can't select any directory, because root "ownCloud" is not displayed"

Comment: Well i can only repeat that i clearly see ownCload in your first picture.

Comment: Btw, I also try to solve it from ownCloud side https://github.com/owncloud/android/issues/3339#issuecomment-1282208452

Comment: The first picture is by selecting single files, here is see ownCloud, but when I try to open directory by ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE I can't see ownCloud

Comment: Hé hé hé. You should have told that at the first line of your post. As the whole time you suggested that it was there.  Well that is no news as many so called document or content providers do not  register for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. We repeat: `if ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE cannot give you the tree then what you want will be impossible.`. OwnCloud is not alone as the same trouble with DropBox and even Google Drive i think.

Comment: do you have a running example to see, how to implement "content providers do not register for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE." ? I can manipulate ownCloud

Comment: No i have not. And probably you have to extend DocumentProvider to start with. Not ContentProvider mmm.. too long ago..